# how to download with temporary url from file server in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have two server. website server and file server. 
i want to create feature for download file with temporary URL from web application server.
my files is exists in the second server.
how to do i this work?

this my plan:
[image: this my plan]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a `Storage::Disk` with sftp driver and then, retrive files from there like a normal folder.

Please take a look to the filesystem documentation: [filesystem docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem).

Comment: by this way, is download traffic on the file server?

Comment: Yes, the webserver act like a bridge. Any particular reason why you asked about traffic?

Comment: i want to be download traffic on the second server and primary server be only requester temporary url from file server

Comment: Please explain further

Comment: Hi could explain but the docs explain it better. In the docs I refered, check "Temporary URLs", it explains everything you need to your specific case ;)

Comment: Well, the file is actually on the file server. So By clicking in the url will download from there.

Comment: From my knowledge, temporaryUrl is a method used on a drivers such as s3 to create a temporary url for a privately stored asset.